# TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator - Tensorflow Custom Metric Callback

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Running into an issue trying to get a custom metric callback to work with Tensorflow. I've created a minimal working example below to help troubleshoot. I'm running:

```
Windows 10
Python 3.6

scikit-learn==0.23.2
pandas==0.25.3
numpy==1.18.5
tensorflow==2.3.0
```

Using the breast cancer binary dataset, I'm trying to invoke the custom metric that was shown as a [solution here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10472#issuecomment-472543538), but running into the above error, probably because I'm not using it right.

This code...

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

# Get binary classification dataset
data = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True)
print(data)
df = data['data']
df['target'] = data['target']

# Train Test split
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size = 0.10, shuffle=False)

# Define features and labels
x_train = train.iloc[:, :-1]
y_train = train.iloc[:, -1]
x_test = test.iloc[:, :-1]
y_test = test.iloc[:, -1]

# https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10472#issuecomment-472543538
class Metrics(Callback):
    
    def __init__(self, val_data, batch_size=20):
        super().__init__()
        self.validation_data = val_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        # print(self.validation_data)
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_recalls = []
        self.val_precisions = []
        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        batches = len(self.validation_data)
        total = batches * self.batch_size
        
        val_pred = np.zeros((total,1))
        val_true = np.zeros((total))
        
        for batch in range(batches):
            xVal, yVal = next(self.validation_data)
            val_pred[batch * self.batch_size : (batch+1) * self.batch_size] = np.asarray(self.model.predict(xVal)).round()
            val_true[batch * self.batch_size : (batch+1) * self.batch_size] = yVal
            
        val_pred = np.squeeze(val_pred)
        _val_f1 = f1_score(val_true, val_pred)
        _val_precision = precision_score(val_true, val_pred)
        _val_recall = recall_score(val_true, val_pred)
        
        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
        self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
        self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
        
        return

# Define a function that creates a basic model
def make_deep_learning_classifier():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=x_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=x_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Get our model
model = make_deep_learning_classifier()
print(model.summary())

# Define some params
batch_size = 32

# Call our custom callback
callback = [Metrics(val_data=[x_test, y_test], batch_size=batch_size)] # < Issue here?

# Start training
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=callback, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
print(Metrics.val_precisions) # < Issue here?
```

...produces this traceback...

```
  File "test.py", line 91, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=callback, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1137, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 416, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, numpy_logs)
  File "test.py", line 54, in on_epoch_end
    xVal, yVal = next(self.validation_data)
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

When I change `val_data=[x_test, y_test]` to `val_data=(x_test, y_test)` in the `callback` variable, I get...

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not an iterator
```

The user who proposed this callback solution mentions something about generators, but I'm not sure how those work. Just trying to define my own custom metric for Tensorflow/Keras. I won't be using this exact callback, but once I get this one running, I can modify it to my own. Just providing it as an example that seemed to work in that GitHub post that I hope someone will be able to point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Using the solution below, I try to properly call my iterator function on my val_data by using

```
iter_val_data = iter(self.validation_data)
for batch in range(batches):
    xVal, yVal = next(iter_val_data)
```

But then I get a too many values to unpack error, so I change it to:

```
iter_val_data = iter(self.validation_data)
for batch in range(batches):
    xVal = next(iter_val_data)
    yVal = next(iter_val_data)
```

Then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 89, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, callbacks=callback, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1137, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 416, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, numpy_logs)
  File "test.py", line 53, in on_epoch_end
    val_pred[batch * self.batch_size : (batch+1) * self.batch_size] = np.asarray(self.model.predict(xVal)).round()
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (57,1) into shape (32,1)
```

Ideas from here? Try and run the code in the same environment as described above if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_next.asp#:%7E:text=The%20next()%20function%20returns,has%20reached%20to%20its%20end.) and as your error messages states, you need to use next() with an iterator. You call `next()` on the list, how should `next()` know, which element is coming next? For that you need an iterator, that saves that state. So this should fix your issue:

```
iter_val_data = iter(self.validation_data)
for batch in range(batches):
    xVal, yVal = next(iter_val_data)
```

Comment: Using that, I get a too many values to unpack error now?

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, however I've since updated my question to a new post which can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858463/need-help-converting-formula-to-tensorflow-style-custom-metric